# IBM Cognos _days_between function not working

Tags: mysql, database, date, cognos

I'm having an issue with Cognos 10. I'm trying to calculate the number of days between to dates so I use the _days_between( date1, date2 ) function.

```
_days_between ([Derniere Date Changement diaphragme] , [Premiere Date Changement diaphragme])
```

I'm quite sure the two Dates are Date objects ( I set them to Dates in the properties anbd the data type from the DB is Date), but I get this error :

```
QE-DEF-0459 CCLException
QE-DEF-0260 Erreur d'analyse syntaxique avant ou près de la position 55 de '_days_between([Derniere Date Changement diaphragme],'
QE-DEF-0261 QFWP - Analyse du texte : days_between ([Derniere Date Changement diaphragme] , [Premiere Date Changement diaphragme])
```

Sorry for the error being in french, the error is a parsing error.
I tried to use the function with "hard" dates, other dates from my DB, but nothing works!

**EDIT** : The function works only if I use _days_between( date1 **;** date2) instead of _days_between( date1, date2) (Why?)

But I still can't calculate the number of days between the two dates. The function returns 0. However, _days_between( [Derniere Date Changement Diaphragme] ; 2015-05-01) works fine.

Any idea what's happening over here?

Comment: Based on the 0261, you've got a syntax error.  If you remove the days between column, do you still get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cognos  _days_between function works with dates, not with datetimes.

Some databases, like Oracle, store all dates with a timestamp.

1. On a query directly to the datasource, try using the database's functions to get this data instead.  When possible, this is preferable as it pushes work to the database which is faster.

Try this in oracle:

```
abs([Derniere Date Changement diaphragme]-[Premiere Date Changement diaphragme])
```

Edit: The error happening on only one of your fields suggests an issue with that date field.  Run a query directly against your MySql datasource and see if the raw data is coming through as a date correctly.

To do a date diff in MySql:
DATEDIFF( [Derniere Date Changement diaphragme], [Premiere Date Changement diaphragme] )

Edit: This second point is not relevant in Cognos 10.  It can be disregarded

2. When you must use cognos functions, convert your incoming date-with-time (datetime) fields to Date without any time (date) with a

   CAST([Derniere Date Changement diaphragme],date)

Comment: I'm working on a MySQL database, so I tried the database's function DATEDIFF(). Same error.

I also tried with the cognos function, with the CAST() function, and again the same error.
I'm sure the CAST syntax is good, because I tried it alone

Comment: I tried _days_between( 2002-04-30 , 2002-06-21 ), the example code, and it doesn't work

Comment: OK! 
So I tried to separate the dates with a ";" instead of ",". And it worked.......
It worked for the example code, but with my values, it just returns zero..

Comment: I don't believe you are correct when you say the _days_between doesn't function doesn't work with date/time. I've used it with date/time many times without issue. Also, almost all of the time the Cognos date/time functions will be converted to the native versions automatically in the generated SQL and thus they will be executed at the database level. You don't need to use native functions, in fact I'd discourage it unless there was a capability in the native function that isn't available in a Cognos function. The reason: portability.

Comment: A simple way to verify where processing is happening is to create a package where local processing is not allowed.  Then run your test.  If you get 'RQP-DEF-0177' then you know cognos is having to process on the dispatcher, instead of pushing the query to the database.   You will see that current_date, _add_days, _days_between all cause local processing.  I just verified this in a Cognos 10.1.1 install, but encourage you to see it for yourself on your own system.  Portability vs Performance is something you will have to weigh for each report.

Comment: Depends on your database.  If a version of the function exists on the database, Cognos will use it.  But still very good advice.

Comment: Good point Andrew.  For the test I mentioned above, I connected to a MySql datasource.  I ran a similar test against an oracle data source and the query did not require local processing.